# How the get the nextAuth session in a middleware

Tags: reactjs, next-auth

I have created a session using nextAuth and next js 4.23.1, and it works, however I dont know hoy to get the session or token in my middleware, I have tried to pass  the handler to the getSession() and doest work at all.

I can get the session in any use clinte component by useSession

How could I get the session and/or token in server side, thanks for your help

**in api/auth/[..nextauth]/route**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { _AUTH } from "@/app/services/shared/endpoints";

export const handler = NextAuth({
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt'
    },

    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        async authorize(credentials, req){
            const res  = await fetch(_AUTH._AUTH_LOGIN, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({user:{...credentials}}),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })
               const user = await res.json()
               if (!user) {
                  return
                } else {
                  return user
                }
            }
        })
    ],
      pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
      }
})
  
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

**middleware**

```
import { handler } from "./app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"


export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

    const session = await getSession(handler)

    if(session !== undefined || session !== null){
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/empresa/mis-empresas', request.url))
    }
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/empresa/mis-empresas',
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the session on the server side, you should not be directly trying to pass your NextAuth handler to getSession. The getSession function works server-side as well, but you need to pass the request object to it.

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const session = await getSession({ req: request });

    if(session){
        return NextResponse.redirect('/empresa/mis-empresas')
    }
}
```

getSession takes an object that should contain the req property, which represents the request. I removed the unnecessary comparison in your if-statement. Checking if(session) should suffice to determine if there's a valid session.Make sure your middleware is correctly configured and executed. Middlewares are a new addition in Next.js 12, so you might want to refer to the Next.js documentation to ensure you've set it up correctly.

Comment: Does `getSession` only work for JWT next-auth implementations? I'm only getting null when passing in the request.

Comment: @akash I tried this and this doesn't work, same as Spencer said, that it always return null... but with getToken it works... so I'm quite confused here tbh...